# I need to emulate the shadows and embossing effects on a picture to my vector design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design

I am designing a menu for a sushi bar and i am inspired by their wall patterns and i wanted to emulate the pattern to the front and back cover of the menu. I redid the shapes on illustrator but i am having a hard time bringing the vector to life. I want to be able to make the vector look 3d and for the shadows and lighting to show. I am new 2 illustrator and im not sure if its possible. Or would i have to design the vector in another program? like cinema 4d or photoshop? thanks alot for the help guys!

here are the pictures.
[image: vector image]

[image: Pattern i want to emulate]

Comment: Try to make a [Gradient mesh](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html)

Comment: although for just starting in Illustrator, that pattern is impressive!  Complex shadow effects are still better done in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

as a quick play, I took your image of the wall, cropped it down, and applied it as a "soft light" overlay of your dark blue color:

[image: wall graphic]
This was in Photoshop, probably your best/easiest way to replicate without pulling your hair out.  Since the wall panels are, well, panels, you could crop down the image to one tile and use it as a repeating image to make the background, or just use something similar to what is above.  The different angles on the panels make for a very pleasing background, IMHO.